# Remove background arrow from date input in Google Chrome v20

Tags: html, google-chrome

Since Google Chrome v20 a new calendar has been added to date inputs. The issue with this is that I'm using javascript to create my own calendar and I have an icon already in the same position as the default chrome arrow.

I was wondering how can I remove the arrow background?

[image: Image showing a dropdown with the arrow]

Comment: Can you post your html please.

Comment: @Nik I'm using a simple <input type="date" /> . This is also visible when applying anywhere else on the web.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436074/change-date-input-triangle-to-a-calendar-icon

Comment: http://jsbin.com/gagojuradu/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As far as I know you can't disable it at the moment.
There is a discussion going on here:
https://plus.google.com/102860501900098846931/posts/hTcMLVNKnec

Perhaps they will add some `-webkit` selectors to control the styling.

For now you might have to use `<input type="text">` instead.

**EDIT:**

As per [Jeremy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15373370/206614), it is now possible to remove the arrow and spin buttons. Details can be found on webkit.org: [Styling Form Controls - WebKit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls#inputelement)

The CSS **to hide** the controls is:

```
<input type="date" class="unstyled" />

.unstyled::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.unstyled::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

However, this will only **hide** and **not disable** the native calendar! - you can still activate the calendar by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> (at least on Windows).

To disable, you need to add a little JavaScript as described on the above webkit.org page:

```
<input type="date" id="dateInput" class="unstyled" />

dateInput.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyIdentifier == "Down") {
        event.preventDefault()
    }
}, false);
```

You can see it working in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/RgY3t/).

Comment: Thanks for answering, I didn't want to remove semantic value to the input but since I'll be using a custom datepicker I guess It won't matter.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly my problem with it - `type=date` is more semantic. But until Chrome (and Opera!) gives the option to disable the calendar popup we might have to use `text` instead.

Comment: Making type='datetime' won't display calendar popup in Chrome and also keep the date validation in IE.

Comment: Yes, but it's because `datetime` is not implemented in Chrome. It is, however, implemented (to some extent) in Safari and Opera so not a perfect solution. See this article: http://swatelier.info/at/forms/dateTime.asp

Comment: The alt + down arrow seems quite overkill to me. Awesome research.

Comment: This isn't answering the question at all. The main question was all about removing just the arrow, not the entire html5 date-picker.

Comment: It's awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

As of this writing, webkit has introduced controls to handle this:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
    /* Your CSS here */
}
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* Your CSS here */
}
```

So, for this particular issue, it would be:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this does not actually remove the spin buttons. The recommended fix for this is `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { display: none; }` as documented on the WebKit wiki. Additionally as indicated by jfrej you need to add some JavaScript to disable the key bindings. See http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls#Dateinputtype

Answer (score 13):

adding to @jfrej: *(cannot comment at the moment)*

To kill all effects chrome applies to the input
You need to clear the "x" (clear) Button too. 
*::-webkit-clear-button*

To prevent the showing of the default text.
Which is not a placeholder or a value you can use 
*::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper*
But be carefull, you cannot see the value anymore.

```
.unstyled::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}



#dateInput:not([value])::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper,
#dateInput[value=""]::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper { 
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/RgY3t/66/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think can right now. They are working on a concept called [Shadow DOM](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/) which will allow you to manipulate and style the default templates. I believe it is available in Chrome Canary so you can try using that.

Answer (score 2):

You can put it like this

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
       background-image: url(images/calendar-icon.png);
       background-position: center;
       background-size: 20px 20px;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
      color: rgba(204,204,204,0);
}
```

by putting the color attribute into 0 opacity you will make the arrow disappear

Answer (score 0):

```
 input[type="date"] {
        &::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
        &::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Here, I have a fontawesome pseudo-icon(caret) at the far right. Therefore, i place the calendar icon in that position, whenever a user clicked on the caret it performs the function of the invisible calendar icon