# Contact Form 7 - remove datepicker spinner

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, spinner

I'm using contact form 7 plugin for wordpress and it's default datepicker has up/down increment arrows (I believe that's the "spinner" from UI, right?).

For the life of my I can't figure out how to remove it. Even going as far as removing the JQUI folders from the plugin dir didn't actually disable the form, so I can't even tell where it's dependencies are coming from...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a wordpress developer but checking the [docs](http://contactform7.com/date-field/) I see:

> Contact Form 7 3.4 and higher supports date type of form-tag. It
>   corresponds with the HTML5 date input type. Currently, only some
>   modern browsers support this input type. Older browsers and some
>   modern browsers don’t support this input type and just render them as
>   traditional text input fields.

I don't think is related to jQuery UI.

So if you want to hide the input type date arrows you can use CSS like:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{
    display: none;
}
```

Ref: [Remove background arrow from date input in Google Chrome v20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418289/remove-background-arrow-from-date-input-in-google-chrome-v20)

Comment: Cheers. Was looking everywhere but somehow missed this. Works great. Thanks again.