# Change the icon of a date type input

Tags: html, css

It is possible to change the icon of a date type input, maybe insert one an image link. I would like the icon to be on the left like now

```
<style>
  input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      opacity: 1;
      display: block;
      background-repeat:  no-repeat;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      border-width: thin
  }
  input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10%;

  }
  input::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      left: 20%;
  }
  input::-webkit-datetime-edit {
      position: relative;
      left: 20%;
  }

  .sd-container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
  }

  .sd {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
  }

</style>

<form>
    <div class="sd-container">
      <input class="sd" type="date" name="selected_date" 
id="date" />
    </div>
</form>
```

1. Edit the icon
2. Change the calendar icon

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/45128029/2030219?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change date input triangle to a calendar icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436074/change-date-input-triangle-to-a-calendar-icon)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="date-block">
<label>
    <span>Дата посещения</span>
    <div class="date">
        <input type="date">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="20" viewBox="0 0 18 20" fill="none">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 2H18V20H0V2ZM2 4V18H16V4H2Z" fill="#282222"/>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 0.25V4.875H12.5V0.25H14.5Z" fill="#282222"/>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M5.5 0.25V4.875H3.5V0.25H5.5Z" fill="#282222"/>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 5.3252H18V7.3252H0V5.3252Z" fill="#282222"/>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M7.54634 8.53906V16.6626H5.54634V12.5137L5.31384 12.6835L4.15137 11.0191L7.54634 8.53906Z" fill="#282222"/>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.3344 10.5352C11.2616 10.521 11.1872 10.523 11.1146 10.5416C11.0418 10.5602 10.9692 10.5958 10.9021 10.65C10.8348 10.7044 10.7741 10.7767 10.727 10.8653L10.2489 11.7636L8.49225 10.7858L8.9703 9.88753C9.14314 9.56274 9.37752 9.27513 9.66224 9.04508C9.94717 8.81486 10.2761 8.64755 10.6298 8.55717C10.9837 8.46675 11.3517 8.45609 11.71 8.52617C12.0683 8.59623 12.4059 8.74477 12.7027 8.95913C12.9993 9.17334 13.2482 9.44814 13.4371 9.7636C13.6259 10.0789 13.7518 10.4297 13.8097 10.7941C13.8675 11.1585 13.8566 11.5317 13.7773 11.8919C13.6984 12.2504 13.5527 12.5913 13.3464 12.893L12.1853 14.6167H13.8486V16.6621H8.37891L11.7067 11.7217C11.7615 11.642 11.8031 11.5473 11.8261 11.4427C11.8492 11.338 11.8525 11.2286 11.8355 11.1219C11.8186 11.0153 11.7823 10.9167 11.7315 10.8319C11.6808 10.7472 11.6177 10.6795 11.549 10.6299C11.4805 10.5805 11.4073 10.5494 11.3344 10.5352Z" fill="#282222"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</label>
```

```
.date-block {
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  label {
    width: 100%;

    span {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      margin-left: 16px;
      color: var(--black, #282222);
      font-variant-numeric: lining-nums tabular-nums;
      font-family: Geologica;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 300;
      line-height: normal;
    }
    .date {
      position: relative;
      input[type="date"] {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 48px;
        padding: 16px;
      }
      input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
        opacity: 0;
        //display: none;
      }
      svg {
        position: absolute;
        right: 19px;
        top: 13px;
        pointer-events: none;
      } 
    }

  }
}
```

Result: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXPLY.png)

Comment: changing icon of input[type="date"]

Comment: Please, use better indentation in the HTML code block, currently it's really difficult to read

Comment: changed, but i don't understand how make this for css code

Comment: I think you can't specify the language the code is in