# disabling future dates in material ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can we disable future dates from the material UI datepicker. What I see is that it does not accept any proptypes as `disableFuture` or `past`.

Here is the github link to the repo [sandboxlink](https://codesandbox.io/s/v333ll1pv5)

Answer (score 3):

You can add `InputProps={{ inputProps: { max: "2017-05-29" } }}` to your `<TextField />` then it will work. For example I took `"2017-05-29"` is the maximum date. I have updated the same in the sandbox provided by you.

```
<form className={classes.container} noValidate>
    <TextField
        id="date"
        label="Birthday"
        type="date"
        defaultValue="2017-05-24"
        InputProps={{ inputProps: { max: "2017-05-29" } }}
        className={classes.textField}
        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
    />
</form>
```

Comment: No .it doesn't work fine .If you click on the upside arrow you can still move to the dates after the maximum dates so it does not serve the purpose .

Comment: If you click up arrow it will increase date, but it will not accept the date while submitting form. Please check HTML5 date inputs for clarity.

Comment: Can we disable this function where no change gets reflected on clicking arrow up after the max date .

Comment: Please go here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418289/remove-background-arrow-from-date-input-in-google-chrome-v20, it is for removing those arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Currently material picker component not fully implemented. Still its uses native input type element. So you can't pass date restriction for future and past. Another way you will create the helper function for the input and validate on each 
date selection.

But I will suggest better to use this library https://material-ui-pickers.firebaseapp.com/installation suggested by material documentation page.

for reference look the documentation.

https://material-ui.com/demos/pickers/#date-pickers

Comment: incorrect answer. you can disable dates. check first answer

Comment: Got it. Material doc little bit confusing. I just seen in doc Textfield structure is like that TextField > Input > input.