# When i move to datetime, scroll is becoming visible

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I use default `<input type="date"/>`

[image]

And when I move cursor to element, scroll is becoming visible.

[image]

Comment: Which DateTime picker you are using ?

Comment: `<td><input type="date" name="StartDateCreate" class="form-control"  /></td>`

`<td><input type="date" name="EndDateCreate" class="form-control" /></td>`
Only bootstrap style. DateTime picker is default html-atribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only scroll bar then, add a class to the element, and load this bellow CSS to work it perfectly.

```
<input type="date" class="unstyled" />

.unstyled::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }
```

If you don't want spin as well as calender, then load this css,

```
.unstyled::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.unstyled::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
     display: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
   }
```

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28748269/2376652)

Comment: Thanks. It's great solution!
But i fix this problem differently. I edit attribute of class "container"
`.container { max-width: 1200px; }`