# remove down arrow on vuetify v-text field with date input

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to remove the down arrow, I have tried applying the styles provided here:
[Remove background arrow from date input in Google Chrome v20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418289/remove-background-arrow-from-date-input-in-google-chrome-v20) .
    For some reason I cant seem to target the correct element. Here is the code:

```
    <template>
        <v-layout justify-start align-center>
          <v-flex sm6 md4>
            <v-text-field
              class="unstyled"
              type="date"
              v-model="rawDate"
              :rules="rules"
              :key="reloadKey"
              ref="dinput"
              maxlength="10"
            >
            </v-text-field>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </template>
     <style scoped>
       .unstyled::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
       .unstyled::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
          display: none;
          -webkit-appearance: none;
      }
    </style>
```

How can I apply the styles to the correct element?
I can see in the dev tools that the `unstyled` class is applied to a parent component but not to the input element I am trying to target.

Comment: If you are going to downvote my question it would be nice to know why???

Comment: Don't understand the downvote too, seems like a normal question, so here, take my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

So this can be done in a rather long way by simply targeting descendants further and further down like so:

```
 .unstyled, .v-input > .v-input-control > .v-input-slot > .v-text-field__slot > input > ::-webkit-inner-spin-button, ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
      display: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
```

Interestingly if I put `scoped` on the style tags it hides the entire date input and I cannot see anything at all.

Answer (score -1):

```
<p>&lt;v-text-field</p>
<p>label=&quot;Prepend inner&quot;</p>
<p>style=&quot;width: 200px&quot;</p>
<p>type=&quot;number&quot;</p>
<p>class=&quot;no-counter&quot;</p>
<p>append-icon=&quot;mdi-map-marker-radius&quot; &nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
<p>&gt;</p>
<div style="color: #d4d4d4;background-color: #1e1e1e;font-family: Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace;font-weight: normal;font-size: 14px;line-height: 19px;white-space: pre;"><span style="color: #808080;">&lt;/</span><span style="color: #569cd6;">v-text-field</span><span style="color: #808080;">&gt;</span><span style="color: #d4d4d4;">&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
.no-counter  input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,.no-counter  input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```