# How to hide v-text-field typed date's icon

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am currently using v-text-field for date inputs by using the following code

`<v-text-field label="Date" type="date"></v-text-field>`

and this will result to a text box with a calendar UI (which then can be used to change the date of the textbox)[image]

my problem is I don't want to display the calendar icon and make the text field itself clickable/editable.
how can I achieve this?

Comment: Check this, its working. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34283800/2463403

Answer (score 1):

### Use Vuetify's `<v-text-field/>` + `<v-date-picker/>`

The best way is to have a `<v-text-field/>` (which has no appended icons by default) that will show a `<v-date-picker/>` on click. It's the same thing, but with a beautifully styled date picker. More info about Vuetify's datepicker [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/).

```html
<v-menu v-model="menu" :close-on-content-click="false" offset-y min-width="290px">
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <v-text-field 
      type="text"
      v-model="date"
      readonly
      v-bind="attrs"
      v-on="on"
      label="Date"
    />
  </template>
  <v-date-picker v-model="date" @input="menu = false"></v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

```js
// script
data: () => ({
  menu: false,
  date: null
})
```

Here's a demo at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-tereshkova-hk3c5?file=/src/components/Playground.vue):

[image]