# Disabled Chrome's HTML5 calendar control

Tags: html, google-chrome

Chrome is automatically adding a calendar widget for any fields that are `<input type="date">` and also adds some strage date formatting to the field as well.  Since the original html spec called for any input type that's not one of checkbox,radio,text,password,file etc being rendered as a normal text field this was how we were triggering our calendar widget.  Is there a meta tag or some other option we can set to prevent chrome from doing this?

Screenshot (please note that this is not our code, chrome is automatically adding this):
[image]

Comment: That's not what the spec called for.  What the spec says is that any unsupported `input` type should be treated as a `text` input.  This has always been the intended functionality of the `date` type, the required date format has always been in the spec.  If you want to hang custom behaviour off the `type` attribute use a value like `custom-date`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable browser native datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320615/disable-browser-native-datepicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to *prevent* the native datepicker is not to give the input a `type="date"` attribute; simply use a straight `type="text"` input.  There are some major advantages of using `type="date"` most notably optimized input capabilities for mobile devices.  But to avoid the picker from displaying you'll have to forego those.

I discuss the advantages and disadvantages of using `<input type="date">` on my blog - http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/30/creating-a-native-html5-datepicker-with-a-fallback-to-jquery-ui/.