# Symfony 2 - How to remove the default date picker of the Date Field Type?

Tags: forms, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

In my formType I use the following to render my Date Field Type.

```
$builder->add('date_naissance', 'date', array(
            'input'  => 'datetime',
            'widget' => 'single_text',
        ));
```

Here belox how it is rendered. My problem is that i want to use a jquery picker and the thing is that the input seems to contain already by default some ugly widget to select the date. My question is simple. How can I get reed of that default date picker. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

[image]

Comment: If this is still bothering you please check the updated answer for the most elegant solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14362310/744975

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not really a problem coming from Symfony. I don't have that kind of datepicker when I generate my date fields. Check your page in different browsers and/or check for some bundles you may have implemented, that generate this field.

Comment: I there. Thank you for trying to help. Your answer was a good hint. I tried rendering the page using Safari and not Chrome and that ugly date picker disapeared. I have to figure out now if it is really coming from Chrome and if yes how to remove that...

Answer (score 13):

**Edit, since symfony 2.6**

**You can now use the html5 field option like:**

```
->add('date', DateType::class, ['html5' => false]);
```

This will remove the html5 `type="date"` on the form view.

---

It is a HTML5 datepicker. the html will have

```
type="date"
```

which is output by symfony by default, as it should.

Chrome will see this and do the datepicker,

**Some ideas to resolve your issue:**

1. Change the format in the form builder:

   `$builder->add('date_created', DateType::class, array(
       'widget' => 'single_text'));`

   Read more here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format
2. Remove browser datepicker: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11470344/744975
3. Override the browsers datepicker with one from another javascript library: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ (My preferred option)

Answer (score 9):

Starting from symfony `2.6` you can set `'html5' => false` in order to disable HTML5 type.

Example:

```
$builder->add('establishment_date', 'date', array(
        'label'   => 'Establishment date',
        'widget'  => 'single_text',
        'html5'   => false,
));
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply change default type to text inside twig:

```
{{form_widget(dateField, {'type':'text'})}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by overriding the `form_widget_simple` in a twig theme (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

```
{% block form_widget_simple %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('text') == 'date' ? 'text' : type|default('text') %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}
```