# Is it possible to change the input type of a CJuiDatePicker?

Tags: yii

I'm stuck with a Yii 1 implementation that has a CJuiDatePicker.  I notice it creates `<input type="text">` but I want it to create a `<input type="date">`.  Is this possible?

I tried using `htmlOptions` to set it but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Not by default, [it would cause issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890376/chrome-type-date-and-jquery-ui-date-picker-clashing) if you replace the text input with a HTML5 date input  (CJuiDatePicker is based on jQuery UI Datepicker). Are you wanting to display a `type="date"` if it's supported by the browser?