# Disable native datepicker in opera

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I want to make a custom datepicker that looks the same in all major desktop browsers. I use jquery-ui for that, managed to disable native datepicker in Chrome but I can't find any way how to do it in Opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any solution how to disable native opera datepicker, so I decided to change type of the input element from date to text, just after initialisation of jquery-ui datepicker. Thanks to that I've got rid of any other native elements like date spinner or clear button. It works perfectly in all up-to-date browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is already answered but there is a better solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320615/disable-native-datepicker-in-google-chrome#answer-12267927).

It says:

---

To hide the arrow:

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
    display: none;
}
```

And to hide the prompt:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{ 
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) can be used to check if browser has native datepicker support. If it exists then Jquery UI datepicker can be added :

```
if (Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
// add here  jquery UI datepicker
```

}

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of modernizr, but I wan't to use my custom datepicker in every browser, no matter if it has a native mechanism or not. Thanks for a reply though.