# How to hide both arrows which comes on mouse over on input[type="date"]?

Tags: html, css

For some reason, I want to hide the both arrow which comes on mouse over to `input[type="date"]` I used `-webkit-appearance: none;` but it's not working. Is there any other way to achive this?

[image]

HTML

```
<input type="date">
```

CSS:

```
input[type="date"], 
input[type="date"]:hover 
{border:0;
background:transparent;
-webkit-appearance: none;}
```

code example http://jsbin.com/vovuha/1/edit

Comment: Here is an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320615/disable-native-datepicker-in-google-chrome

Comment: @Pugazh I want to hide both arrows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide all effects on hover you can use:

```
pointer-events: none !important;
```

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)