# Toggle input type for date and password

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 disabled input fields and I want to remove password type on hover, but the date is not consistent, it doesn't change to password when I hover over the input field directly. The text works fine. I wonder why it acts like this and how it can be fixed

```js
$('[data-masked="text-container"]').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).children('input').attr("type", "text");
})

$('[data-masked="text-container"]').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).children('input').attr("type", "password");
})

$('[data-masked="date-container"]').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).children('input').attr("type", "date");
})

$('[data-masked="date-container"]').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).children('input').attr("type", "password");
})
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-masked="text-container">
  <input type="password"
         disabled
         value="hello">
</div>
<div data-masked="text-container">
  <input type="password"
         disabled
         value="yooooo">
</div>
<div data-masked="date-container">
  <input type="password"
         disabled
         value="2013-01-08">
</div>
```

Comment: It's work fine on FireFox, not on Chrome. I suppose it  is a bugg on WebKit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of experimentation with `console.log()` showed that the event handlers were not being reliably triggered for the `date`-type input.  Thinking about what is different between a `text` input and a `date` input, well obviously the `date` input includes [all kinds of fancy date-related stuff](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) that the browser renders, some of which is dependent on mouse clicks and position.  So presumably something about that is interfering with the normal mouseover handlers.

From there it was a simple bit of searching to find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169578/how-to-hide-both-arrows-which-comes-on-mouse-over-on-inputtype-date) which describes how to disable much of that fancy `date`-input related stuff - by using this CSS:

```
pointer-events: none !important;
```

And adding that to your example code solves the problem.

```js
$('[data-masked="text-container"]').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).children('input').attr("type", "text");
})

$('[data-masked="text-container"]').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).children('input').attr("type", "password");
})

$('[data-masked="date-container"]').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).children('input').attr("type", "date");
})

$('[data-masked="date-container"]').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).children('input').attr("type", "password");
})
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
input[type=date] {
    color: blue; /* just to confirm our css is being applied */
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-masked="text-container">
  <input type="password"
         disabled
         value="hello">
</div>
<div data-masked="text-container">
  <input type="password"
         disabled
         value="yooooo">
</div>
<div data-masked="date-container">
  <input type="password"
         disabled
         value="2013-01-08">
</div>
```