# Simple way to stop browser native datepicker

Tags: datepicker

I found many posts talking about stop native browser datepicker. But all of them have long and complicated solutions. Can I have just simple solution to do that?

```
<input type="date">
```

Or you may help me in understand the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320615/disable-native-datepicker-in-google-chrome)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable native datepicker in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320615/disable-native-datepicker-in-google-chrome)

Comment: @byako I know it is, I mentioned that for help how to use it as alternative solutin. You do not understand me :(

Comment: If you need another answer, please explain _why_ the previous responses are not satisfactory. Just saying that they is too complicated is not helpful, because people won't known what to improve. Alternatively, you can post a comment for explanations under the previous answer.