# JQuery UI datepicker not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I am using Jquery UI date picker in my asp.net MVC app. All works fine in IE but in Chrome the default date picker is also visible, when I use JQuery UI it doesn't add the date to the box.

I have several options that are on here as possible solutions but nothing works.

The ViewModel is:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

The View is:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "01/12/80" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The script for the date picker is :

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker({
        format: "yyyy/MM/dd",
        startDate: "-120y",
        endDate: "-10y",
        startView: 2,
        calendarWeeks: true,
        defaultViewDate: { year: 1975, month: 01, day: 01 }
    });
</script>
}
```

I can't be the only one who needs to solve this issue and hopefully it already has been. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disable the default datepicker. See this post: [Disable native datepicker in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320615/disable-native-datepicker-in-google-chrome)

Comment: Hasn't made a difference unfortunately @Marcus Abrahao

Comment: did you inspect the element to make sure DateOfBirth is his id?

Comment: Ok, sorry.. I miss understood your question. I guees your input is type date, correct? So you have to disable the default datepicker

Comment: if so... try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320615/disable-native-datepicker-in-google-chrome

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge, but where would I place the answer : input[type="date"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{ 
    visibility: hidden !important;
} ?

Comment: In your css file or in a style tag

Comment: tried this on the editorfor @style = "input::- webkit - calendar - picker - indicator{display: none;}} })" and also in the site.css with no joy

Comment: You can't change Html.EditorFor to Html.TextBoxFor ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91213/discussion-between-marcus-abrahao-and-phill-sanders).

Comment: I have tried that and it solves it but textboxfor looks very basic and I don't know how I can match its look to the editorfor

Comment: do you mean to use class and placeholder? @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth,  new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "01/12/80" } )