# From where this date picker is included and how to set default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datepicker

[Here](http://pasteboard.co/cuSgKEdjS.png%3E) you can see the date picker but the code I used is basic.

`<div class="field">
  <%= label_tag("To date") %>
  <%= date_field_tag 'tdate', '2016/07/01', class: 'form-control' %>
</div>`

I don't know how date-picker is included here. I didn't worried about it until I tried to set default value '2016/07/01' to it. But as you can see in image its not appearing.

I even tried removing JQuery from application.js and bootstrap also doesn't have any class for a regular `<input type= "date">`.

I don't have any problem with date-picker (its very nice actually). All I need is default value to be shown.

Bootstrap classes are used for CSS. Rails 4.2.6 and ruby 2.2.4p230.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the feature of [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) and it follows the [ISO format](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm).

In the above code the default value has the date separator as slash "/". According to ISO format the date separator should be hyphen "-".

The below code should work.

`<div class="field">
  <%= label_tag("To date") %>
  <%= date_field_tag 'tdate', '2016-07-01', class: 'form-control' %>
</div>`

**How to disable native date picker? (For Google chrome)**

This question already asked here [Disable native datepicker in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320615/disable-native-datepicker-in-google-chrome) and has an answer suggested by @Yacine Zalouani,

To hide the arrow:

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
    display: none;
}
```

And to hide the prompt:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{ 
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```