# How do I disable blazor InputDate component's datepicker?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-editform

Given:

`<Input Date class="form-control" @bind-Value="item.Birthday" />`

How do I prevent the datepicker from popping up, while still taking advantage of the date masking?

Comment: What do you mean by "date masking," and why do you want to prevent an html input from inputting?

Comment: I'm assuming the OP wants to disable the calendar, but keep the native date formatting such as MM/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution requires CSS and is not specific to Blazor.

But here is some sample code written in Blazor that I tested and verified in Google Chrome:

```cs
@page "/"

<style>
    input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<EditForm Model="@myPerson">
    <InputDate class="form-control" @bind-Value="@myPerson.Birthday" />
</EditForm>

@code {
    Person myPerson = new Person();
    public class Person
    {
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Reference: [Disable Native DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267927/10787774)